# Contact form problem - I do receive messages, but no contents (blank page)

Tags: php, email, forms, hosting, contacts

I have a contact form on site which used to work, but since last few months has stopped working properly.  This could have been due to some coding error that I can't figure out.  What happens is that I receive the messages sent, but they are completely blank, with no contents at all.  What could be the problems?

I'm attaching first the front-end page, and then the back-end.

Sample of contact.php the front-end code:-

```
<div id="content">
     <h2 class="newitemsxl">Contact Us</h2>

<div id="contactcontent">
        <form method="post" action="contactus.php">
Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="Name" /><br />
Email:<br />
<input type="text" name="replyemail" /><br />
Your message:<br />
<textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea><br /><br />

<?php require("ClassMathGuard.php"); MathGuard::insertQuestion(); ?><br /> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
* Refresh browser for a different question. :-)

</form>
</div>

</div>
```

Sample of contactus.php (backend code):-

```
<?php

/* first we need to require our MathGuard class */
require ("ClassMathGuard.php");
/* this condition checks the user input. Don't change the condition, just the body within the curly braces */
if (MathGuard :: checkResult($_REQUEST['mathguard_answer'], $_REQUEST['mathguard_code'])) {
    $mailto="questions@stylishgoods.com";
$pcount=0;
$gcount=0;
$subject = "A Stylish Goods Enquiry";
$from="DO_NOT_reply@stylishgoods.com";
echo ("Great, you're message has been sent !"); //insert your code that will be executed when user enters the correct answer
} else {
    echo ("Sorry, wrong answer, please go back and try again !"); //insert your code which tells the user he is spamming your website
}


while (list($key,$val)=each($HTTP_POST_VARS))
{
$pstr = $pstr."$key : $val \n ";
++$pcount;
}
while (list($key,$val)=each($HTTP_GET_VARS))
{
$gstr = $gstr."$key : $val \n ";
++$gcount;
}
if ($pcount > $gcount)
{
$comments=$pstr;
mail($mailto,$subject,$comments,"From:".$from);
}
else
{
$comments=$gstr;
mail($mailto,$subject,$comments,"From:".$from);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably there was a PHP upgrade on the server and `$HTTP_POST_VARS` has been deprecated.
Use `$_POST` and `$_GET` for those.

Comment: So wherever it is written:- '$HTTP_POST_VARS', I should replace with '$_POST' and wherever it is wriiten '$HTTP_GET_VARS', I should replace with '$_GET'?

Answer (score 2):

is it possible that your php version has changed? In php5 the HTTP_POST_VARS array is no longer available.

You can try the following the get your values before you start your while loop:

```
$HTTP_POST_VARS   = !empty($HTTP_POST_VARS)   ? $HTTP_POST_VARS   : $_POST;
```

Comment: This line that you've mentioned, should I add it just above the while loop?

Comment: yepp , or repleace $HTTP_POST_VARS with $_POST in your sourcecode